# How do I remove images from the Downloads folder that are visible from within certain apps, but not visible from any file manager?

Tags: file-management, google-apps, cache

**Background:** I used to use the Share with another app button on Google Chrome to send images from Google Chrome App to my Text Messaging App. It would go to my text message but not be seen in the Downloads folder.

Now, if I have a file stored in the Downloads folder that I want to attach to either a Text Message (via Messaging App) or an Email (via Gmail App), when I go to upload that file from the File Explorer within one of those Apps, all of the images that I have ever "Shared" in the method described are listed there, and can be clicked and uploaded as though they are stored in the system. However, when I use a File Management App, they are not there.

I simply want to remove the images from the Downloads folder, or from appearing as though they are in the Downloads folder to certain Apps (i.e., Messages and Gmail). Also, I'd like an appreciation of what is going on, but I think that would be clear upon a solution being presented.

I am not interested in rooting my phone.

**What Has Not Worked:**

• Clearing cache of Google, Google Chrome, and Messages Apps

• Deleting the Downloads folder in its entirety.

• Downloading multiple File Explorers and Hidden Image/File Apps to Search for the Locations of the Files

• Granting storage permissions to Google Chrome Apps

Comment: The file manager shows the truth. The other apps show the Android media service cache. The simplest way to update the cache is to reboot the device. Or use one of the "sd-scanner apps".

Comment: That's because those images are still in the servers of those particular apps and not in your device. They will be removed eventually.

Comment: While rebooting the device did not work (these images have been cached for over a year and were in fact on my device), your 'Android media service cache' comment gave me some insight. After clearing the cache on all Android system apps, the problem has been resolved. Specifically, I believe it was the 'Download Manager' system app cache. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

That's because those images are still in the servers of those particular apps and not in your device. They will be removed eventually.

Edit: The problem has been solved by the OP himself. I did not quite understand the situation when I wrote this answer. Please refer to the comments bellow.

Comment: That is not true. The images could be clicked from the Download folder and added to the email or text message from those apps. This could be done despite a lack of connectivity. They have also been on my device for over a year now, in some cases. It is not a transient issue.

Comment: @Joe So you are saying that you can't access them directly from the downloads but you can access them through certain apps?

Comment: Yes. I have (mostly) resolved the issue as commented above by clearing the cache of my 'Download Manager' Android System App. There are still two greyed out files that were there before, but unlike the other dozen or so images, they are broken links and cannot in fact be attached to a text or email.

Comment: Update: Clearing the data in addition to the cache of the Downloads and Download Manager system Apps has entirely solved this issue.

Comment: Good to know. Mark something as the answer and close the question.